# Iterate through List of single character strings using indexOf()

Tags: java, list, encryption, indexof

I'm making a program that will take an input string and decode it using the Rot13 encryption method. This takes the alphabet, and rotates it by 13.

I'm having a hard time getting the index of a letter in the list, and every time I run it it gives me -1 as if the item is not in the list. I looked in the java documentation, and indexOf() asks for an object. I tried explicitly typing my input as an object but that didn't work either.

This is the code I have so far:

```
package rot13;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author andrewjohnson
 */
public class CipherKey {

    List<String> alpha = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", " ");
    List<String> alphaRev = Arrays.asList("Z", "Y", "X", "W", "V", "U", "T", "S", "R", "Q", "P", "O", "N", "M", "L", "K", "J", "I", "H", "G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A", " ");

    public String codeDecode(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            //System.out.println(ch);
            int x = alpha.indexOf(ch);
            //System.out.println(x);
            String y = alphaRev.get(x);
            System.out.print(y);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String readInput() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter message to be encoded or decoded");

        String s = br.readLine().toUpperCase();
        //System.out.println(s);

        return s;

    }
}
```

And my main():

```
/**
 *
 * @author andrewjohnson
 */
public class Rot13 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CipherKey x = new CipherKey();


        x.codeDecode(x.readInput());
    }

}
```

I'm not sure why it is not working, but I've narrowed it down to the line:

```
 int x = alpha.indexOf(ch);
```

Not being able to find ch in alpha. I'm new to Java and I've tried everything that I can think of. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
char ch = s.charAt(i);

int x = alpha.indexOf(ch); // <-------- HERE
```

You are searching for a `char` in a `String` array. Which of course doesn't exist. Hense the `-1`

Change it to `int x = alpha.indexOf("" + ch);`

or `int x = alpha.indexOf(Character.toString(ch));`

or `int x = alpha.indexOf(String.valueOf(ch));`

Any of these will do.

Comment: That worked like a champ! Thank you!
My program says: GSZG DLIPVW ORPV Z XSZNK! GSZMP BLF!

I added an if statement to where if x == -1, to print ch, so it accounts for the punctuation that is not in the list.

Comment: @AndyJohnson  please note that your algorithm where you perform a linear search of the list (with `.indexOf`) to find the matching character is _very_ inefficient.  This answer solves the immediate problem, but not the algorithm.

Comment: I'm aware. It would be better to only use one array and some math to find the rotated index 13 places away. This is just an exercise to teach me Java. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

`ch` is of type `char` and your list contains `String`. List may accept `Object` for `indexOf`, but the type still counts.

Change `int x = alpha.indexOf(ch);` to `int x = alpha.indexOf(String.valueOf(ch));` to fix it.

Example:

```
System.out.println(alpha.indexOf('D'));
System.out.println(alpha.indexOf(String.valueOf('D')));
```

will print

```
-1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

1. That is not the rot13 algorithm - you just appear to be reversing the alphabet.  rot13 maps the range `A - M` to `N - Z`, and vice versa.  Two invocations of rot13 give you back the original text.
2. ASCII letters follow a numerical sequence.  Instead of performing a linear search through a list to find the matching index, it's *far* faster to just calculate the difference between the current letter and `A`, and then use that difference to offset into a second array of characters (or a string).

i.e.

```
static String map = "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM";  // for rot13

function rot13(String input) {
    StringBuffer output;
    for (char ch : input) {
        int index = ch - 'A';
        if (ch >= 0 && ch < 26) {
            output.append(map.charAt(index));
        } else {
            output.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

NB: untested, may not compile, E&OE etc